# Kill all views/controllers and default to Login page on home button not working for web service calls

Tags: ios, web-services, uiview, controller, appdelegate

I have a LOGIN view which is the root view controller. After the user is logged in and anytime during the app if he clicks on home button, I remove all the possible subviews using: **[view removeFromSuperview]** recursively so I can kill all views. I even use **[controller removeFromParentViewController]**.

However, if any web service calls were running when we click on iphone home button, even though all views & controllers were removed, the response from the web service is processed by the app and it crashes due to **Push** segue being called. How can I kill any existing web service calls in the app in the AppDelegate? Error **" Could not find a navigation controller for segue "XXsearch".** This error is obviously because I remove all the controllers and views.

But why does the web service response still get processed? Is there another way I can kill the web service calls?

The web service calls are asynchronous. But why do the controllers still exists to deal with the response?

This is the web service call:

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:NSMutableURLRequestObject delegate:self];
```

This is the code in the controller which is a delegate to the web service:

```
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
         // do something with response object
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"XXsearch" sender:self];
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code for the network requests? Any answer would just be a guess otherwise.

Comment: @Clever Error: Just added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for `connectionWithRequest:delegate:`

> During the download the connection maintains a strong reference to the delegate. It releases that strong reference when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.

This means that even though you are removing the view controller, the `NSURLConnection` is forcing it to stay around. First of all, you'll want to save the connection in property in your view controller.

```
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:NSMutableURLRequestObject delegate:self];
```

Then you'll need to make sure you cancel the connection and set it to nil when your view controller is removed from its parent view controller.

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    [super didMoveToParentViewController:parent];
    if (!parent && self.connection) {
        [self.connection cancel];
        [self setConnection:nil];
    }
}
```

Also, you'll want to make sure you set the connection to nil when the connection finished or fails.

Comment: This explains a lot of the behaviour. Thank you. Why do you set connection to nil?

Comment: Just for cleanup. After you cancel a connection, there is nothing else you use the object for.